# Environment variable that influences version of cp output?

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system

Write the command that will tell you which version of cp will be executed when you
type cp at your prompt. What environment variable influences the output of this
command?

for the first part i already check and the answer is version-- cp.
can anyone help for the second part?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by output from `cp`? As far as I'm concerned this is the 'copy' command in unix and produces no output. The `which cp` command will tell you where the command is, and the `$PATH` environment variable governs which command is picked up when you type `cp` on the command line.

Comment: The output means the version-- cp output.

Comment: I've never heard of the `cp` command having different versions, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: im not very sure also thats why asking here. cause this question is given by my lecturer.

Comment: I can only refer to my original comment:

1. `which`
2. `$PATH`